# Importing Apache poi in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This is my first time trying to use external libraries and I'm having trouble getting it to work. I tried following this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project) and got to [this step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wcW1.png) and as a result I got an [empty library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74c3f.png). If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy way to manage Your externals libraries in [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/). Use one of this and all Your problems will gone.